# Constraining zooming and panning in a D3 map viewport

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How would I go about fixating the viewport on a D3 (v4) map, such that users cannot zoom and pan outside of this viewport? Say I wanted to fix the viewport on South East Asia, and that my starting point is this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/5Lf0w3sm/1/). So pseudo code would be something like:

```
...constrainViewport([[x0,y0],[x1,y1]])
```

where `x0`,`y0`,`x1` and `y1` are the coordinates of the bounding viewport rectangle.

I have seen the [following block from Sean Connelley](http://bl.ocks.org/sconnelley/9558967) however the solution presented is very complicated and out of date (v3). Happy to say I don't understand what is going on there either. Is there really no better (or 'native') way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `zoom.translateExtent([a,b])` where a is a coordinate representing the top right and b is a coordinate representing the bottom left of the panning extent (it will constrain zoom when zooming out too).

Since you are working with geographic data, you can set your limits fairly easily in degrees of latitude and longitude:

```
  // extent bounds (arbitrarily chosen)
  var topLeft = projection([-180,80]);
  var bottomRight = projection([0,-20]);
  zoom.translateExtent([topLeft,bottomRight])
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4syupL0o/).

Comment: This answer is perfect. Thanks Andrew!